# changing text in attribute value of jquery dynamically

Tags: jquery, replace

I have the following jQuery code:

```
var fnVal = $(_placeHolder[0].parentElement.children[0]).attr('onclick');
```

While debugging I can see the value of `fnVal` as

```
function onclick(event) { 
    javascript:DisplayData($('#divexpand')[0],'true'); 
}
```

I wish to replace `true` in `DisplayData` function to `false`.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: I assume you're looking for something programmatic, rather than simply changing the `onclick` attribute of the element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign it a new function which will replace the old one (also no need for jQuery in this):

```
_placeHolder[0].parentElement.children[0]).onclick = function() {
    DisplayData(document.getElementById('divexpand'),'false'); 
};
```